# Homogeneous restriction

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

If $G$ is a finite group and $N$ is a normal, abelian subgroup of $G$. What means a homogeneous restriction of an irreducible representation of $G$ to $N$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain it in characters. If $\chi \in Irr(G)$, and $N \unlhd G$ is abelian, then in general the restriction $\chi_N$ splits in several linear characters of $N$. But homogeneous means $\chi_N=e\lambda$ for some $\lambda \in Irr(N)$. Note that $e=\chi(1)$. It also holds that $\chi(1) \mid |G:N|$.